# Actually undo git stash pop

Tags: git

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20038056/undo-git-stash-pop) had the same title but it is **NOT** the same question. That question is really asking "Discard results of git stash pop". This question is actually

### **UNDO** git stash pop

in other words

```
// in branch foo
git stash
git checkout bar
git stash pop       # ERROR. I didn't want to pop on top of bar, lots of conflicts
git stash undo-pop  # NEED COMMAND TO PUT STASH AND LOCAL FILES BACK AS THEY WERE
git checkout foo
git stash pop
```

Is there a way to get everything back to the state just before I typed `git stash pop`? In other words to actually **UNDO** the pop and put the stashed stuff back into the stash and put the local files back in the state they were before I typed git stash pop.

This is also not a dupe of [How to recover a dropped stash in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89332/how-to-recover-a-dropped-stash-in-git)  Although that might be helpful in certain situations

Comment: In general you can use `git stash` again for this.

Comment: I can't use `git stash`, the files are in a conflicted state on top of `bar`.

Comment: Then put this information in the question because it makes a big difference.

Comment: It is in the question. Also that's the entire point of the word **UNDO**.

Comment: I too run into this periodically, and it is tricky to deal with when there were previous staged files (or at least not obvious for newbs). `git stash` doesn't have `--abort` like `git merge` and `git rebase` do; that would be nice. Please up-vote this: https://github.com/git/git.github.io/issues/599

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In your example, to restore to the state before `git stash pop`, use:

```
git reset --hard bar
```

This form of the `git reset` command restores the state of the index *and* the working directory to the head of the `bar` branch.

Because you had conflicts on the first `git stash pop`, the stash *remains* on the top of the stash stack.

From there, you can `git checkout foo` and `git stash pop` again.

Answer (score 11):

[Greg Hewgill's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48619473/1256452) is right (and upvoted, and the OP should accept it) but there's are several additional caveats here, in case anyone wants to use the answer in a more general fashion.  Let's look first at the *specific sequence of commands used:*

> ```
> git stash
> git checkout bar
> git stash pop       # ERROR ... lots of conflicts
> ```

Now, let's list the caveats:

- It's important that `git stash pop` has failed.  (Greg already noted this.)
- You *did not* use `git stash --keep-index` when creating the stash.
- After running `git stash`, *you* made no changes to your work-tree.
- The `git checkout` command succeeded, so *it* may have made changes to your work-tree—in fact, it must have done so for the `pop` to fail—but your work-tree is still "clean", as `git status` would say.

It's this last point, that `git status` would (before the attempt to `git stash pop`) tell you that your work-tree is `clean`, that is the key.  Had you made changes to your work-tree, either before or after `git checkout bar`, you would be in more trouble.

Because you did not do those things, `git reset --hard` is the answer.

#### Why this is the case

What `git stash` does, in general, is make two commits.  One saves the current *index* and the other saves the current *work-tree*.<sup>1</sup>  These commits are slightly special in a few ways; the most important is that they are on *no branch at all*.<sup>2</sup>  Having made its commits, `git stash` then normally runs `git reset --hard`.<sup>3</sup>

What the `git reset --hard` step does is to make the index and work-tree match the current commit.  That is, we've saved the (whole) index and (the entire tracked part of the) work-tree in the stash; so whatever is *different* between the current `HEAD` commit and the index, can be re-set to be the *same* again; and whatever is *different* between the `HEAD` commit and the work-tree, can be re-set to be the same again.

After the `git reset`, both the index and work-tree are "clean", as `git status` will say: they both match the `HEAD` commit.  You can then `git checkout` other branches, as you have no unsaved work.  You can then attempt to `git stash apply`, or even `git stash pop`, to "move" your changes to this other branch.

When that fails—as in this case—the stash remains in the saved stashes.  The current index and work-tree are now full of merge conflicts.  If you run `git reset --hard`, Git will re-set the index and work-tree to match the `HEAD` commit as usual, so that you'll be back to the same situation you were in after the `git checkout` step.  Since you had no unsaved work (your *saved* work is still in the stash commits), you're OK here.

(If you *did* have unsaved work, the `git stash apply` step will have mangled that unsaved work by attempting to merge the stashed work-tree changes.  This is very difficult to undo, in general.)

---

<sup>1</sup>While `git stash` typically makes two commits, if you run it with `--all` or `--include-untracked`, it will make *three* commits.  I like to call these the `i` (index), `w` (work-tree), and `u` (untracke files) commits.

When using `--all` or `--include-untracked`, the `save` or `push` step will do more than just `git reset --hard`: it will also run `git clean` to remove whatever went into the third commit (untracked-only files, or untracked-including-ignored files).  You may have to repeat this `git clean` work before applying such a stash, which is tricky and annoying.

Later, when you run `git stash apply`, Git will (try to) apply the `u` commit if it exists.  It will always (try to) apply the `w` commit.  It will (try to) apply the `i` commit *only* if you give it the `--index` flag.  There are some minor bugs in many versions of `git stash` surrounding this whole "separate index restoration" stuff.  They tend to affect people who want to use the `--keep-index` and `--index` flags in, e.g., pre-commit hooks.

Note that `git stash pop` is just `git stash apply && git stash drop`: that is, attempt to apply the stash, and then, *if Git thinks the `apply` went well, also `drop` the stash*.  I find it better to use `git stash apply` first, to avoid dropping the stash *even if* Git thinks it went well, because Git and I sometimes disagree as to what "went well" means. :-)

<sup>2</sup>Git uses the name `refs/stash` to remember the current stash, and (ab)uses the reflog for `refs/stash` to maintain the remainder of the "stash stack".  Branch names internally all have the form `refs/heads/name`, so `refs/stash` is not a branch name.

<sup>3</sup>If you use `git stash --keep-index`, it runs more than just `git reset --hard`: it extracts the saved index state to the work-tree.  The goal here is to leave the work-tree set up the way the index was set up, so that you can test what you were about to commit.  As noted in footnote 1, there's a small but fairly nasty bug here with many versions of `git stash`, where the stashed work-tree state accidentally takes the index version instead of the work-tree version if the correct work-tree version matches the `HEAD` version.

Answer (score 1):

So, I'm not 100% sure of the answer in all cases. In my case when I typed `git stash pop` and I was on branch `bar` there were conflicts. So while it applied the stash it didn't drop the stash. So to undo and correctly apply the stash to branch `foo` it was just

```
git reset --hard      # resets bar to before the stash pop
git checkout -b foo
git stash pop
```

If there had been no conflicts with branch `bar` then it's just

```
git stash             # restash
git checkout -b foo
git stash pop
```

Comment: If you pop a stash and there are no conflicts, then to undo a `git stash pop` you just `git stash` again.

Comment: Are you sure? Is it possible when merging with `bar` some merges would match and therefore the diffs getting re-stashed would not match the original stash that was meant for a different branch? I guess it's just storing the state of the tree not the diffs so then yea, `git stash` should work

Answer (score 1):

You can reverse patch the stash (which as already mentioned should still be there as git wont drop a stash if it doesn't apply cleanly)

```
git stash show -p stash@{0} | git apply -R
```